# Facebook login with Azure Service and get user info error

Tags: facebook, azure, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I've implemented facebook login following this blog https://ahoycoders.com/2015/07/09/xamarin-forms-social-authentication-with-azure-mobile-services-part-3/

That blog is based on old Azure portal. 
But, I'm using new Azure portal.
1. In the new Azure portal I used Easy APIs option for creating custom API as mentioned in the blog.
2. I copied the scrip mentioned in the blog for my custom API and I'm using only Facebook.

I authenticated via Facebook and then called the following,

return await mobileService.InvokeApiAsync("getextrauserinfo", HttpMethod.Get, null);

Unfortunately, I'm getting the following error,
"Cannot read property 'getIdentities' of undefined"

I don't know what's wrong, please help me in fixing this.

Comment: have you managed to solve this ?

Comment: No @Daniel I implemented it native using FB SDK. I did not use Azure.

Comment: I guess FB SDK doesnt support uwp apps yet?

Answer (score 0):

currentUser is no longer obtained from request as .user, it is now request.azureMobile.user

They changed the method calls. It is also no longer getIdentities.

Its getIdentity.

A few other calls slightly changed as well. 
I suggest anyone wanting to use that guide use console.log to see what each object actually returns and then switch out the old code for the right call.

Logic in that example should still be fine, just slightly different calls/names.